# Setting the text color of preferences screen

Tags: android, radio-group, textcolor, preferencescreen

Friends I have created a listpreferences screen ,and it is working fine but I want to change the color of text appearing on the list and the RadioGroup items. So can anyone help me out.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <ListPreference      
         android:entries="@array/gametype"
         android:entryValues="@array/gametype"
         android:key="listpref"
         android:summary=""
         android:title="Set Game Level" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is my preferences screen.
    After Clicking on listpreferences item it show a dialog box which has three options 
    so i want to change the color of that radiobutton text and the list item text.

here is java code:

```
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
        SharedPreferences sp=getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();
        Preference pref=findPreference("listpref");
        ListPreference lp=(ListPreference)pref;
        pref.setSummary(lp.getValue());
        sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {
        Preference pref=findPreference(key);
        ListPreference lp=(ListPreference)pref;
        pref.setSummary(lp.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: Post some code so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void setcolor(int position){
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    if(i==position)
    {
        list.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(238, 180,    180));
    }
    else{
        list.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this ;

```
RadioGroup.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```

This is good solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a consistent colouring scheme in the whole application I'd suggest learning about adding a theme or styles. This should get you started http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html.

Answer (score 0):

Use Html.fromHtml to style your text.

```
mPodFolderPref.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>" +  mPodFolderPref.getTitle() + "</font>"));
mPodFolderPref.setSummary(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>" +  mPodFolderPref.getSummary() + "</font>"));
```

Html.fromHtml can do a lot for you.

Mal